# php open and close tag and scope syntax

Tags: php, html, sql, session, scope

How am I suppose to be using the "`<?php`" and "`?>`" syntax properly. I have found out you can mix the open and close tags with open and close braces to allow for other languages in between, but am I doing it correctly? The welcome page is triggering the else statement when it should be entering the if statement.

I want to make each page inaccessible unless the user has logged in, so I it set up this way.

Here is the login file code

```php
    <?php
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$password = md5($password);

require_once('connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `login_info` WHERE `uname`='$uname' && `password`='$password'";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();

$count=$stmt->rowCount();
if($count==1)
{
    echo "Login success";
    $_SESSION['log']=1;
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
    header("refresh:1;url=welcome.php");

}
else
{
    echo "Login Credentials Not Found";

    echo"<a href='index.php'><br/><br/>Back to Login Page</a>";
}
?>
```

and here is the welcome.php

```php
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['log']))
{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#quicklinks 
{
  padding-right: 15px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <h2>LINKS</h2>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="welcome.php" >Welcome</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="findwords.php" >search users favourite words</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="editwords.php" >edit your favourite word</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="antclicker.php" >play the ant game</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="antgameleaderboard.php" >ant game world leaderboard</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="chat.php" onclick="window.open('chat.php','newwindow','width=450,height=650'); return false;">chat</a>
    <a href="index.php" >logout</a>
    <p>Hello and welcome to my website!</p>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
else
{
    echo "You are not logged in, please login";

    echo"<a href='index.php'><br/><br/>Login Page</a>";
}

?>
```

As you can see the php code is broken up around the html code, but the separate php blocks are directly related. I would imagine the simplicity of `$_SESSION['log']=1;` and `if(isset($_SESSION['log']))` should work. The issue is that the welcome page reverts to the else statement, although the 'log' index has to be set, right? This is why I think it must be a scope issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** You are correctly using the syntax. Except, that you forgot to call `session_start();` in the first example.

**Longer answer:** You could also use the [alternate syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), to make the code more readable:

```
<?php
  require_once('connection.php');

  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['log'])):
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#quicklinks 
{
  padding-right: 15px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <h2>LINKS</h2>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="welcome.php" >Welcome</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="findwords.php" >search users favourite words</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="editwords.php" >edit your favourite word</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="antclicker.php" >play the ant game</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="antgameleaderboard.php" >ant game world leaderboard</a>
    <a id="quicklinks" href="chat.php" onclick="window.open('chat.php','newwindow','width=450,height=650'); return false;">chat</a>
    <a href="index.php" >logout</a>
    <p>Hello and welcome to my website!</p>
</body>
</html>

<?php else: ?>
    You are not logged in, please login
    <a href='index.php'><br/><br/>Login Page</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the end it's a matter of choosing one style and sticking with it, in order to stay consistent.

Comment: Thanks! Also what if I want code to live in the if statement and code to live out of it, if there is no scope braces, hows does php know?

Comment: I don't think I understood the question  Can you post some code (pastebin or similiar) to explain what you mean? :)

Comment: you are using the syntax ```if():``` the colon means what? If I dont use ```{}``` how will I know what the if statement and else affects? usually you have ```if(){}``` then ```else{}``` not ```if():``` then ```else():``` what does the ```:``` do and what does it contain?

Comment: That is the [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) I was talking about :) Everything after `if(something):` will be executed (of course only if `something` is truthfully) until it encounters an `else:`, `elseif(somethingElse):` or finally an `endif;` statement. The alternative syntax drops the `{}`. `if():` is the same as using `if(){` and then `endif;` is equal to the closing bracket `}`

Comment: ahhhh endif, okay, like older languages. I guess that is good and makes it more readable thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to add `session_start();` to your login file. Without this, the SESSION super-global won't work.